# Magento 2 Form key

Tags: magento-2.1, forms, form-key

```
if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
  // do something
}
```

Any Magento 1 equivalent in Mangento 2 for `_validateFormKey` function.

And Can anyone explain how and where Magento checks `formkey`, when any form is submitted.

Basically I am not able to validate the `formkey` in controller, My form is submitted even if change the `formkey` value from inspect element.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try following way:

```
protected $formKeyValidator;

public function __construct (
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator
) {
    $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
}
```

And then

```
if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
    // invalid request
}
```

Comment: It's not working in Chrome but working properly in firefox.

Answer (score 2):

There is also in Magento 2 a form key validator

```
Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator
```

Have a look on the customer loginPost controller to see an example of its use

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Add formkey inside the form like below and follow the above steps for validating in controller.

```
<?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some previous answer is correct but I am elaborate it.

```
namespace Equaltrue\Themeoption\Controller\Taxmode;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    protected $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator
    )
    {
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            // form key is validate
        }
    }
}
```

Now you may face a problem if you use localhost in user like
URL: http://localhost/magento2/

The Form Key from website & Magento will not match. You can check it from following Magento core file.

vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/FormKey/Validator.php

Now you have to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 or your IP.